# Binding to MvxSpinner SelectedItem property not working

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, selecteditem, mvxbind, mvxspinner

I use a MvxSpinner to show country phone prefixes in a combobox in a MvvmCross for Xamarin app. I can bind to the ItemsSource property correctly, so I can see the list of my prefixes but when I assign the property in my view model that is bind to the SelectedItem property of the MvxSpinner, it won't work and will always show the first element in the list as the selected item.

The way I do it is the following. In my ViewModel I get the user data from the server and assign the properties for Country and PhonePrefix. Then I get the list of all countries and prefixes also from server and bind them to the list properties that are binded to the ItemSource properties of the respewctive MvxSpinners (simplified):

```
    public string PhonePrefix { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; } = new Country();

    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; } = new List<Country>();
    public List<string> Prefixes { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    private async Task GetUserData()
    {
        try
        {
            var userDataResult = await _registrationService.GetLoggedInUserData();

            if (userDataResult != null)
            {
                if (!userDataResult.HTTPStatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
                {
                    Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert(userDataResult.Error?.Message);
                }
                else
                {

                        PhonePrefix = userDataResult.user.country_code_phone;
                        PhoneNumber = userDataResult.user.phone;
                        Country.id = userDataResult.user.person.addresses[0].country_id;
                        Country.name = userDataResult.user.person.addresses[0].country_name;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error<RegistrationViewModel>("GetUserData", e);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the view model properties for Countries and Prefixes with information retrieved from the server
    /// </summary>
    private void ProcessFormData()
    {
        if (_registrationFormData != null)
        {
            Countries = _registrationFormData.Countries?.ToList();
            var userCountry = Countries?.Where(c => c.id == Country?.id).FirstOrDefault();
            Country = IsUserLogedIn && Country != null ? userCountry : Countries?[0];

            var prefixes = new List<string>();
            if (Countries != null)
            {
                foreach (var country in Countries)
                {
                    //spinner binding doesn't allow null values
                    if (country.phone_prefix != null)
                    {
                        prefixes.Add(country.phone_prefix);
                    }
                }
            }

            //we need to assign the binded Prefixes at once otherwise the binding for the ItemSource fails
            Prefixes = prefixes;
            PhonePrefix = Prefixes.Count > 0 && !IsUserLogedIn && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PhonePrefix) ? Prefixes?[0] : PhonePrefix;
        }
    }
```

And in the axml layout:

```
    <MvxSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/spnrCountry"                   
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Countries; SelectedItem Country"/>
    <MvxSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/spnrPrefix"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Prefixes; SelectedItem PhonePrefix"/>
```

On the output window I can see the following error regarding MvxBinding:

```
(MvxBind) Null values not permitted in spinner SelectedItem binding currently
```

I debugged and I never have any Null values in the lists or in the properties I bind to the ItemSource and SelectedItem properties of the MvxSpinner.

Actually the Countries ItemSource and SelectedItem work properly so if user saved it's country to be Argentina, when I load it's data the selected item in the spinner will be Argentina. Note that I use a Country entity like that:

```
public class Country
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool favorite { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_de { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public int rzl_code { get; set; }
    public string phone_prefix { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I also tried to make the phone prefix in it's own entity wrapping a string value but it didn't work either.

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? Why for the Countries it's working and for the prefixes not?

I use PropertyChanged.Fody.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting about `null` is because `SelectedItem` in the spinner does not allow `null` as a selected item. So if you want to display an empty item one solution is to add another fixed item that has an empty value, i.e. in the case of `PhonePrefix` you can set `string.Empty` and add it to the list of `PhonePrefixes` and in your `Country` you can set the first one as default or create a stub `Country` with name `None` for example and add it to the list of countries.

Another point to take into account is that when you want to update the view you have to be sure that you are notifying it in the Main Thread. You are trying to update the `PhonePrefix` in a `Task` of another thread so the view does not get noticed.

You should update `PhonePrefix` by doing:

`this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => PhonePrefix = userDataResult.user.country_code_phone;
);`

This will take care of doing the set of `PhonePrefix` directly on the Main thread so your view will be notified correctly.

---

**Update**

After better looking at your question and own answer and seeing that you use `PropertyChanged.Fody` I can guess that the problem was in fact how you are assigning the `PhonePrefix`.

`PropertyChanged.Fody` defaults behaviour is to add [Equality Checking](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/EqualityChecking) which replaces your property code

```
public string PhonePrefix { get; set; }
```

for something like

```
private string _phonePrefix;
public string PhonePrefix
{
    get
    {
        return _phonePrefix;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!String.Equals(_phonePrefix, value))
        {
            _phonePrefix = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PhonePrefix");
        }
    }
}
```

so when you do in the `GetUserData()`:

```
PhonePrefix = userDataResult.user.country_code_phone;
```

and in the `ProcessFormData()`

```
PhonePrefix = Prefixes.Count > 0 && !IsUserLogedIn && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PhonePrefix) ? Prefixes?[0] : PhonePrefix;
```

`PhonePrefix` is not null or whitespace so it tries to reassign the same value but because fody adds the equality checking it does not get assigned again and therefore it does not raise the change of the value, so the view does not get notified.

The assignation in `GetUserData()` I think it may be being done in another thread and that's why the view does not get notified. 
According of what you said `Country` does get updated in `ProcessFormData()` so in order to `PhonePrefix` to be updated too in that place you should only add the `[DoNotCheckEquality]` attribute to the property to avoid the equality checking and that should be all.

```
[DoNotCheckEquality]
public string PhonePrefix { get; set; }
```

If it does not work you should add the invocation on the main thread too (I advise you to see in debug on which thread is the method being executed to see if you do need the invoke on main thread).

HIH

Comment: I understand the error message. I never said I wanted to display an empty item in the solution. About the main thread point, it's not true, as the Country and Countries properties are bind properly in the other spinner.

Comment: In order the View to get updated you must do the notification in the Main Thread, as I don't know how you called `GetUserData()` I supposed that it was being done in a backgorund thread. Regarding that you never said you wanted to display an empty item in the solution I like giving more information in an answer that's why I give that explanation, cause maybe to you is not useful but to somebody else it might be. I'll try to see in your solution why it works

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. It really makes sense. Let me try!

Comment: It did work! So I will need to be careful when assigning my view model properties next time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It does work, as PhonePrefix is set in GetUserData, also you should set Country. From your code Country is null, this is why you are getting the first item from the list selected or error also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it was not related to the Country being null. I just forgot to put it in my simplified snippet. Countries and Country properties are bind properly and show no error

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a weird solution and still don't really understand why, I found a way to make it work. I have the feeling it has something to do with asynchronism.

The problem was assignin the PhonePrefix property in the GetuserData() method and then reassign it in the ProcessFormData(). So now the code that works looks like that:

```
private string _phonePrefix;
public string PhonePrefix { get; set; }
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public Country Country { get; set; } = new Country();

public List<Country> Countries { get; set; } = new List<Country>();
public List<string> Prefixes { get; set; } = new List<string>();

public override async Task Initialize()
{
    await base.Initialize();
    IsUserLogedIn = await _authService.IsUserLoggedIn();
    if (IsUserLogedIn)
    {
        //get user data from server, show user data
        await GetUserData();
    }

    //get countries, prefixes
    if (Countries.Count <= 0 || Prefixes.Count <= 0)
    {
        _registrationFormData = await _registrationService.GetRegistrationFormData();
        ProcessFormData();
    }

    AddValidationRules();
}

private async Task GetUserData()
{
    try
    {
        var userDataResult = await _registrationService.GetLoggedInUserData();

        if (userDataResult != null)
        {
            if (!userDataResult.HTTPStatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert(userDataResult.Error?.Message);
            }
            else
            {

                    //PhonePrefix = userDataResult.user.country_code_phone;
                    //can't bind it here to the public binded property because the SelectedItem binding fails. 
                    //I first assign it to a private field and then use it in the ProcessFormData method
                    _phonePrefix = userDataResult.user.country_code_phone;
                    PhoneNumber = userDataResult.user.phone;
                    Country.id = userDataResult.user.person.addresses[0].country_id;
                    Country.name = userDataResult.user.person.addresses[0].country_name;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error<RegistrationViewModel>("GetUserData", e);
    }
}



    private void ProcessFormData()
    {
        if (_registrationFormData != null)
        {
            Countries = _registrationFormData.Countries?.ToList();
            var userCountry = Countries?.Where(c => c.id == Country?.id).FirstOrDefault();
            Country = IsUserLogedIn && Country != null ? userCountry : Countries?[0];

            var prefixes = new List<string>();
            if (Countries != null)
            {
                foreach (var country in Countries)
                {
                    //spinner binding doesn't allow null values
                    if (country.phone_prefix != null)
                    {
                        prefixes.Add(country.phone_prefix);
                    }
                }
            }

            //we need to assign the binded Prefixes at once otherwise the binding for the SelectedItem fails
            Prefixes = prefixes;
            if (Prefixes.Count > 0 && !IsUserLogedIn && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_phonePrefix))
            {
                PhonePrefix = Prefixes?[0];
            }
            else
            {
                PhonePrefix = _phonePrefix;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note the addition of a private property _phonePrefix to hold the phone prefix value in the GetUserData() and then assign it's value to the property that it's bind in the view, the PhonePrefix.

Actually I can't really explain why this happens, so it would be nice if somebody could explain this behavior.

Comment: could you add where do you call `GetUserData()` and `ProcessFormData()`?

Comment: are you using `PropertyChanged.Fody`? because if you do I think I know which was the problem at first and why it does work now

Comment: Yes, I do. I will update the question stating that! Can't wait to hear your answer

Answer (score 0):

The properties that you are using are not notifying the changes to view, for this you must use:

`string _phonePrefix;
    public string PhonePrefix
    {
        get => _phonePrefix;
        set => SetProperty(ref _phonePrefix, value);
    }`

Comment: when you use https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged you don't need to do that. It automatically does it for you